# Align text and image horizontally in wellpanel R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, panel

I build a wellpanel in Shiny with an image and a text block. I put them in seperate columns and expected them to just be next to each other. Shiny thought otherwise and refuses to align them. The text seems to be on a different row than the image and I don't see why it doest that.

[image]

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  wellPanel(
    fluidRow( 
      column(3, img(height = 105, width = 300, 
                    src = "logo_pcfruit.jpg")),
      column(9, offset = 3,
        p("De perenbladvlo vormt één van de voornaamste perenplagen in Europa. 
        Perenbladvlooien voeden zich met plantensap dat ze uit bladknoppen en jonge scheuten zuigen. 
        Deze zuigactiviteit leidt tot directe schade aan perenbomen onder de vorm van bladmisvorming en groeiremming. 
        Het teveel aan suikers dat ze uit het plantensap opnemen, scheiden perenbladvlooien -net als bladluizen- uit als honingdauw. 
        "),
        p("Perenbladvlooien overwinteren als adult en leggen vroeg in het jaar een eerste generatie eitjes. 
        De uitgekomen larven doorlopen 5 stadia alvorens ze een laatste keer vervellen tot adult en op hun beurt eitjes leggen. 
        "), 
      )
    )
  )
)
```

(Sorry for the large text input, but otherwise the lay-out is less clear.)

I have no experience whatsoever with CSS and HTML, so a Shiny solution would be nice. If that's not possible, CSS or HTML are fine.

I've posted a similar question about the titelpanel last week. 
I now think both cases are caused by the same problem, but which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself: the problem is the `offset` argument in `column()`. Without it, the image and text are aligned nicely. Same answer for the titlePanel problem.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  wellPanel(
    fluidRow( 
      column(3, img(height = 105, width = 300, src = "logo_pcfruit.jpg")),
      column(9,
        p("De perenbladvlo vormt één van de voornaamste perenplagen in Europa. 
        Perenbladvlooien voeden zich met plantensap dat ze uit bladknoppen en jonge scheuten zuigen. 
        Deze zuigactiviteit leidt tot directe schade aan perenbomen onder de vorm van bladmisvorming en groeiremming. 
        Het teveel aan suikers dat ze uit het plantensap opnemen, scheiden perenbladvlooien -net als bladluizen- uit als honingdauw. 
        "),
        p("Perenbladvlooien overwinteren als adult en leggen vroeg in het jaar een eerste generatie eitjes. 
        De uitgekomen larven doorlopen 5 stadia alvorens ze een laatste keer vervellen tot adult en op hun beurt eitjes leggen. 
        "), 
      )
    )
  )
)
```

[image]

(EDIT: I used a different image for this screenshot than I did in the question, the different box size is not a flaw)